# Fast Report generator tool for Java SE

Tags: java, reporting

Anyone know about Fast and Easy Report Generating tool for Java SE applications?
I want to get data from
* SQL Database
* Generate Barcodes
 ( all options on Jasper) but I want any other Program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try BIRT reporting tool? The link to the page - https://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/

Comment: I don't know. I've used it with eclipse.